# Sub-collection request (Firestore, Coroutine)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

Trying to stick to the MVVM pattern rules. The final data should come to the ViewModel (I'm making an exception for Glide, but that's not the point).

Created several subcollections in the document (likes, comments, images, and so on).

After creating them, I ran into the problem of requesting the Firestore inside the main request. The data just doesn't have time to arrive.

How do I wait for data before "data.add" in such a situation?

ViewModel

```kotlin
    init {
        data = loadData()
    }

    fun getData(loadNextData: Boolean): LiveData<Response<List<Model>>> {
        if (loadNextData)
            data = loadData()

        return data
    }

    private fun loadData(): LiveData<Response<List<Model>>> {
        return liveData(viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Response.Loading)

            val result = repository.loadData()
            if (result is Response.Success || result is Response.Error)
                emit(result)
        }
    }
```

Repository

```kotlin
    suspend fun loadData(): Response<List<Model>> {
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            if (LAST_DOCUMENT == null) {
                firebaseRepository.getReference(DEFAULT_COLLECTION_NAME, DEFAULT_ORDER_FIELD, DEFAULT_ORDER_DIRECTION)
            } else {
                firebaseRepository.getReference(DEFAULT_COLLECTION_NAME, DEFAULT_ORDER_FIELD, DEFAULT_ORDER_DIRECTION, LAST_DOCUMENT!!)
            }
            .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { query ->
                    try {
                        LAST_DOCUMENT = query.documents.lastOrNull()

                        query.documents.forEach { document ->
                            document.toObject(ModelDTO::class.java)?.let {
                                it.id = document.id
                                it.likes_count = // TODO
                                it.comments_count = // TODO
                                it.images_uri.add(//TODO)
                                data.add(it.mapToEntity())
                            }
                        }
                        continuation.resume(Response.Success(data))
                    } catch (exception: Exception) {
                        continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resume(Response.Error(exception))
                }
        }
    }
```